# Manual toggle for darkMode - SASS - SCSS

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, darkmode

I have an ionic project which uses the `prefers-color-scheme: dark` media query to listen to OS default theme settings & applies as preferred.  I also have my images swapped between using the `<picture>` && `<source>` tags.

I now added a manual toggle incase the user wanted to use light/dark theme independent of the OS default settings.  However I do not know how to change the image.. I currently have a toggle on/off if preferDarkTheme.media == true or false.  The image defaults to the OS otherwise nothing is rendered.

Any idea on how I can change the image too with manual toggling?

Comment: please post the related code.

Comment: So I have `:root { --color: blue }`

`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
--color: red;
}`

I then do this in my component..

`<picture>
              <source srcset="assets/logo-landscape-dark.svg" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />
              <img src="assets/logo-color.svg">
            </picture>`

This works fine when it comes to OS default theme.. but not in a manual toggle